# Turn the dataset into a script, creating the dataset

Tags: r

Are there any ways to turn the dataframe (imported from excel) into a code, which creates this dataframe?
I have a dataframe, which I obtain from excel, but I'd love to get the code like this from it.

```
abc <- data.frame(a = c("a", "aa", "r"),
              b = c(1, 2, 3),
              c = c(T, F, T))
```

Comment: Do you want a file that when read creates the data.frame? Then your best option is `save(abc, file="abc.RData")`. When read back with `load("abc.RData")` the data set will be created in the globalenv with the same name, without the need to assign to a variable like `read.table` and other functions do.

Comment: There is also `dump("abc", file = "abc.R")`, note that the object must be quoted and that the output file is a R code file.

Comment: You might be looking for `?dput`.